# Lowering the stem on a Canyon Endurace

Tags: road-bike, bike-fit, stem

I have a Canyon Endurace XL frame with a 110mm stem which I currently have slammed. I've started racing this year and am very comfortable in the drops for the entire race, which makes me think that I might have room to go a little lower. 
Would I be better getting a stem of the same length but with a -17deg angle which would effectively buy me another 21mm to play with? Or should I go for a longer reach? Or both?

Comment: Can you flip the stem?  That's probably the cheapest option.

Comment: Road bikes generally come with the stem pointing down. Canyon is no exception.

Comment: Yes the stem is turned down already so that option's out. New stem is the next cheapest option before replacing the frame.

Comment: Have a look at bike shops on your area, if you're lucky one might have something like a [Giant Powerfit](https://www.giant-bicycles.com/gb/showcase/powerfit) that they'll let you play with to try out stem lengths and drops in exchange for buying from them.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on your body proportions. Canyons have very high head tubes, so -17 degree stem is nothing out of ordinary. Longer stem is a good idea if you feel that the cockpit is too short.

For reach, in my opinion a classic bend bar is better than "ergo" because it has longer reach on the drops, which increases the difference between hoods and drops.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your body proportions you should go for a longer stem. 1cm longer is a huge difference already and will make you much more aero.